# Starting an Activity and delaying its transition

Tags: android, view, android-activity, transition

I have 2 activities :

  - activity A is gathering data from internet (it takes some time)

  - activity B is building UI elements based on the data previously received (it takes some time too)

When activity A start downloading, the app enter a loading phase. When it's complete, activity B starts, so I have a transition between the views of A & B. Then B requires also a loading phase.

I have loading - transition - loading - result which doesn't look nice at all.

I would like to have loading - transition - result where the loadings of both activities are grouped.

So my question is : is there a way to start the activity but to delay the transition ?

Comment: "Then B requires also a loading phase": with loading phase, you mean 'drawing phase' that the system takes to draw the UI, right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you are going the right way about this. I would suggest just having one activity with a loader. Then use something like `AsyncTask` to load the data in a different thread. Update the UI as the data gets loaded and then when everything is done remove the loader. You should use multiple threads to do work that takes time because otherwise your UI will freeze. Looking at what you said above, I don't see why you would need two activities.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an ActivityGroup: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityGroup.html

This would allow you to achieve what you want. I don't think it's possible without it - (if you really need to wait until all UI elements representing the data are drawn. Otherwise I would suggest to follow Amir's advice below).

You put both activities into the ActivityGroup, but hide B at the beginning (visibility=gone). Then you can swap the visibility / do the transition once the data is loaded and the UI for B is built.

I'm curious though what kind of layout/UI you have that takes so long to build, if the data has already been preloaded in A.

Comment: ActivityGroup is deprecated